# Joda Time only comparison

Tags: java, jodatime

I am trying to compare Time only and facing an issue while trying to compare. I am extracting the UTC Time using JODA as follows

```
DateTime ld_currentTime = DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.UTC );
Date ld_time = ld_currentTime.toDate();
```

Now, i would like to compare this time to another time in a string variable which is like

```
String start = "09:00";
```

The required functions i seek are either outdated or not able to parse the functionality. For example, the `isAfter()` seeks a long variable as an argument. So is the case with other functions. But i am converting current time to UTC, prior processing. 
The only option seems left out is to fetch hours and minutes separately into int variables and process them.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found a logical solution. Didn't try for any discrepancies in it. Any comments / Suggestions are appreciated. Let me check whether it works fine in all cases or not.

```
for (int li_tmp_ctr=0;   li_tmp_ctr < gi_total_elements;   ++li_tmp_ctr){
    LocalTime now = LocalTime.now( DateTimeZone.UTC );
    LocalTime limit = new LocalTime( IX_Container[li_tmp_ctr].utc_open_time );

    if (now.isAfter( limit) ){
        //  Write the information to the appropriate file. 
        lb_startFlag = true;
    }
}
```